# Is it absolutely correct that nil'ing a Firebase DatabaseReference does NOT stop the observation?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

In the **Awesome that is Firebase**, you do this

```
    var r1: DatabaseReference? = nil
```

and then this

```
    r1 = Database.database().reference(withPath: "score/bucks")
    r1!.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in ... }
```

and then have fun,

but eventually you must do something like this

```
private func clearObservations() { // call from viewDidDisappear

    if r1 != nil {

        r1?.removeAllObservers()
        r1 = nil
    }

    if r2 != nil {

        r2?.removeAllObservers()
        r2 = nil
    }

    .. etc etc etc etc etc etc :/ :/
}
```

***{ Critical aside: it's worth noting YOU CAN NOT do that in deinit, you MUST do it in viewDidDisappear }***

It does seem pretty incredible that one cannot just

```
      r1 = nil // and this will remove the observor
```

Is it **honest to goodness** the case that:

- if you just nil a `DatabaseReference`,
- i.e. you do NOT bother to `removeAllObservors`,
- in fact the observation ***will*** just keep going?

Is that right?

I just want to absolutely clarify this and get it down on the record - it will probably help future googlers (interestingly, I couldn't really google up a clear marginalia on this anywhere).

I realize you can put them in a hokey array, etc, but it seems incredible that nil'ing one does **not** stop the observation?!

---

*Footnote*

One thing that's always disturbed me. If you carefully read the doco for `removeAllObservors`, really all it asserts is that it drops or terminates the closure you added.  It doesn't, really, say that `removeAllObservors` actually has the guts of Firebase in the iPhone, actually call home and stop doing the observation. I spend a lot of time worrying about that detail.

Comment: It's been awhile I havn't used swift but as far as I remember, you would be good to go as long as you set the handler to nil. I suppose it's easy to test it. Cheers

Comment: I'm guessing that because you have other references to the database it's still observing. You get the reference from a static class that keeps the live reference even when you nil your reference. So it's pretty reasonable to keep observing

Comment: hi @Yitzchak - your logic does make sense, thanks for that thought.  It would be good to get an absolutely definitive answer on this!  From someone who knows the library codebase.   I am the world's #1 fan of Firebase, but it is an "amazing hole" in the iOS side that the most basic consideration - stopping observing when you, say, move away from a screen - is not handled fully and clearly.

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in the comments, you must remove observers manually because Firebase hold references to your DatabaseReference and to your closures. If you nil the DatabaseReference it's not deallocating it, it has another reference to it.

I guess from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference) that this what's happening

Many times you'll see in the docs:

> Use removeObserverWithHandle: to stop receiving updates.

So this is the way, and the only way.

Comment: Thans again.  Just TBC, **r1.removeAllObservers** also works fine - right?!  (As far as I know!)   Assuming that you created it as in the first line of my example code, **r1 = Database.database().reference(withPath: "score/bucks")**.  Do we know this?  :O

Comment: For clarity, **I believe** an unrelated common source of confusion is, people try: **Database.database().removeAllObservers()** - which does **nothing**.  You have to of course have kept all the references - as in the "r1" example here.  I think  :)

Comment: You need to remove observers from every child level as written in docs